# Consider flipping a coin twice and the following events. Which events are independent?

Tags: probability, independence

Consider flipping a coin twice and the following events:

$A-$ the flips come up the same

$B-$ the first flip comes up heads

$C-$ the second flip comes up tails.

Which events are independent?

**BACKGROUND AND MY WORKING**

Now, this question apparently came in my test and I answered it wrong. The options included were:

$i)$ $A$, $B$ & $C$

$ii)$ Only the three pairs of events.

$iii)$ All events are dependent on others.

The right answer is $ii)$. Now I don't understand what does it mean by only three pairs of events? Doesn't it say $A$, $B$, and $C$. and most important question how do I know intuitively and by reading the statement of the problem that the events are independent, without utilizing the definition of independence, i.e: If $Pr(A\cap B)=Pr(A)Pr(B)$ then $A$ and $B$ are independent events.

Comment: The point is that $A,B,C$ are *pairwise independent* of one another.  We have $\Pr(A\cap B)=\Pr(A)\Pr(B)$ for instance, same for $A,C$ and for $B,C$.  The three however happen to not be *mutually independent* since $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)\neq \Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$.

Comment: The phrasing and grammar of this seems unfortunately confusing, but that may be a copying error on your part.  You should verify the exact phrasing as given.  As for "*How do I know intuitively...the events are independent without utilizing the definition*"  practice?  Intuition shouldn't always be trusted in these scenarios however and the definition should be the way to go.  There are a number of scenarios where intuition might say one thing but it happens in reality to be the other, for instance the first card in the deck being a queen is independent of the second card being a heart.

Comment: There must be a sign that indicates that the events are independent, isn't there any?

Comment: Also how did you know that these events are pairwise independent and but three together mutually aren't independent. That's the point I don't understand

Comment: From experience, I recognize the problem.  To prove it, you must first understand that results of consecutive coin tosses are *modeled* as being independent (*inb4 chaos theory and butterfly wings get involved*) so we automatically get that $B$ and $C$ are independent for free.  Also we should have had in the problem statement that the coin was fair.  As to check $A$'s independence of $B$, find $\Pr(A\mid B)$ and compare that to $\Pr(A)$, you will find both are equal to $\frac{1}{2}$, proving their independence.  For $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$ that is obviously zero and not $\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$

Comment: The only rigorous calculation necessary was in finding $\Pr(A\mid B)$ and $\Pr(A)$.  For comparing $\Pr(A\cap B\cap C)$ all that was necessary was to recognize this was the empty event and thus probability zero since you can not have both coins the same while also having the first coin heads and second tails.  Those contradict eachother.  On the other hand $\Pr(A)\Pr(B)\Pr(C)$ is the product of three non-zero numbers and as such non-zero.